# Using MGFs to determine independence of sum and difference of two variables $(X+Y$ and $X-Y)$

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

I have a question for class that asks: Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. Unif$(0,1)$. Are $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ independent?

In an earlier part of the question I found that the covariance between (X+Y) and (X-Y) was 0, but I know this does not necessarily mean independence. My professor advisd that I use their MGFs, because I know that if they are independent then:

$$ M_{(X+Y)+(X-Y)}(t) = M_{X+Y}(t) \cdot M_{X-Y}(t) $$

I think that if I let W = X+Y:
$$ M_{W}(t) = M_{w_1}(t) + M_{W_2}(t) = M_{X}(t) + M_Y(t) $$

and if I let U = X-Y:
$$ M_{U}(t) = M_{U_1}(t) + M_{U_2}(t) = M_{X}(t) + M_{-Y}(t) $$
(but I'm not really sure how to handle the negative).

and finally, if I let Z = (X+Y)+(X-Y) = X + Y + X - Y = X + X:
$$ M_Z(t) = M_{Z_1}(t) + M_{Z_2}(t) = M_{X}(t) + M_{X}(t) $$

I also know that because X and Y are i.i.d. their MGFs should be the same. So it looks like:

$$ M_{(X+Y)+(X-Y)}(t) = 2 \cdot M_X(t) $$

and

$$ M_{X+Y}(t) \cdot M_{X-Y}(t) = 3 \cdot M_{X}(t) + M_{-Y}(t) $$

BUT, if that negative signed in $M_{U}$ worked out differently, so that it was $M_X(t) - M_Y(t)$ when I know the MGFs are the same, then the whole thing would come out differently! Both MGFs would ultimately be $2 \cdot M_X(t)$ and they would be independent. (Based on a passage in my text, I think they're supposed to come out independent). So is this whole approach bad, or is it possible I mishandled the negative?

Comment: They are dependent.  For example, the events $X-Y<-\frac12$ and $X+Y<\frac12$ both have nonzero probability, but the are mutually exclusive (otherwise we would get $2X=(X+Y)+(X-Y)<0$ with nonzero probability).

Comment: Ok, looking back at the text I think I was reading a section too broadly, and it was only speaking to bivariate normals. So I do think now that I was wrong and you are right- they should come out dependent. Do you happen to have an opinion on whether the work makes sense/answers the question?

Comment: The transformation here has a geometrical interpretation in the 2D space: it is a rotation of $45^{\circ}$ followed by an enlargement by the factor of $\sqrt{2}$. The original $(X, Y)$ has a rectangular (square) support, and after rotation it is no longer "rectangular" - in the sense that it no longer parallel to the axis. In such case they cannot be independent. You can pick out the corners as an illustration. E.g. $\Pr\{X + Y \in (2-\varepsilon, 2)\} > 0, \Pr\{X - Y \in (1 - \varepsilon, 1)\} > 0$ but these two events cannot happen simultaneously for sufficiently small $\varepsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MGF of $X+Y$ is $$M_{X+Y}(t)=M_X(t)M_Y(t)=\left(\frac{e^t-1}{t}\right)^2$$
Similarly, the MGF of $X-Y$ is 
$$M_{X-Y}(t)=M_X(t)M_Y(-t)=\left(\frac{e^t-1}{t}\right)\left(\frac{e^{-t}-1}{-t}\right)=\frac{e^t+e^{-t}-2}{t^2}$$

Now, the $MGF$ of $(X+Y)+(X-Y)$ is equal to the MGF of $2X$, i.e., 
$$MGF_{(X+Y)+(X-Y)}=M_X(2t)=\frac{e^{2t}-1}{2t}$$ 
Just putting this together shows that $$M_{(X+Y)+(X-Y)}(t)\neq M_{X+Y}(t)\cdot M_{X-Y}(t)$$
hence $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are not independent. However, as said in the comments, this is not the fastest way to do it. It suffices to use your intuition (that if you know $X+Y$ then you already know something about $X-Y$ as well) and find an event that violates the independence condition.

Comment: Thank you, this was so helpful. Although I am also starting to see why this is not the fastest way.